# Python terminal application with interface like nano

Tags: python-2.7, terminal

This may be a stupid question but I'm not sure how to phrase it in a google-friendly way...

In a terminal if you type something like:

```
nano some_file
```

then nano opens up an edit window inside the terminal. A text based application. Ctrl+X closes it again and you see the terminal as it was.

Here's another example:

```
man ls
```

How can I make a text based terminal application in python?

I hope this question makes sense, let me know if you need more clarification...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick:

http://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html

Example:

```
import curses
oScreen = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.curs_set(0)
oScreen.keypad(1)
oScreen.addstr("Woooooooooooooo\n\n",curses.A_BOLD)
while True:
    oEvent = oScreen.getch()
    if oEvent == ord("q"):
        break
curses.endwin()
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to use alternative screen buffer. To enable it just print '\0033[?1049h' and for disabling '\0033[?1049l' (Terminal Control Escape Sequences).
http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#The%20Alternate%20Screen%20Buffer

Example:

```
print('\033[?1049h', end='')
print('Alternative screen buffer')
s = input()
print('\033[?1049l', end='')
print('Normal mode')
print(s)     `
```